# Whatsapp Messages Deletion - Multiple Selection

Tags: whatsapp

How to delete multiple messages in a conversation on Whatsapp?

Answer (score 4):

You could delete all messages in a conversation or messages for set time periods by going to **info** in the app bar menu for a conversation and then **clear chat history** in the app bar menu of the info page.

Other than that it appears that selecting more than one message for deletion is currently not possible.

Comment: `It appears that selecting only certain messages for deletion is currently not possible.` You should probably clarify that this is true only if you want to delete multiple messages. This makes it sound as if you cannot delete even one single message.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there you can select multiple message on whats app
Just touch on left corner of the message and than other msg... There you will see that you can select multiple message on what's app

Answer (score 1):

Tap on the left corner of the message. Then you can select multiple messages for deleting or forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

In latest version(v 2.12.126.0) of WhatsApp, delete multiple selection feature is available. Just tap in the left side of the messages and you will get the check boxes to select. Once selected, touch the delete icon in the bottom. That's it.